# Wide Windows phone? What view is this?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I fat fingered something when hitting debug and now I am stuck in this view.

Ive never seen it before, have no idea how I did it and would LOVE to know how to undo it.

Mind you this is a Windows Phone 8 app.

[image]

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
    x:Class="mycuts.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="add" Text="add" IconUri="/images/add.png"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="del" Text="delete" IconUri="/images/minus.png"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="RT APPS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="My Cuts" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,161,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBox x:Name="cutsList" Height="451"/>

            <!--<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"/>-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the Blend or Visual Studio 2012/2013 Designer can go wacky like that. You can do one of two things:

1. Close and Reopen the XAML page
2. Shut down and reopen Visual Studio

Usually the first option fixes it for me, but the second one always does.

Happy coding!